# Cakephp + enum support : unable to save or select enum 0 and 1

Tags: cakephp, enums

When I am saving data having two enum fields to manage to manage status of message i.e. read or unread by user. I am using enum ('1','0') to manage status  '1' => read and '0'=> unread

following code will save the message but in status column saving empty filed

```
$data = array(
              'message' => 'test message',
              'status' => 1
             );

$this->Message->save($data);
```

database structure is as follow

```
Field                Type                  Collation          Null    Key     Default 
------------------  -------------        -----------------  ------  ------  -------  
id                   bigint(20)            (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)   
message              varchar(255)          (NULL)             NO      MUL     (NULL)                                                         
status               enum('0','1')         latin1_swedish_ci  NO      MUL     0
```

even I have used data array as

```
$data = array(
              'message' => 'test message',
              'status' => '1'
             );


$data = array(
              'message' => 'test message',
              'status' => "'".1."'"
             );
```

Comment: Is using type 'bool' not possible?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim Joyce, mark, Daniel I can't change the database schema because same database is used to create web services for i-phone and android applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using cakephp - it does (as documented) not support ENUM.
and in your case it is wrong to even use enums in the first place. Enums are used for more than two states and should be emulated as ArrayDatasource or in your model (as I do).

But "read/unread" is a boolean (two definite states!).

and there is an easy way to accomplish this correctly:

```
tinyint(1) [unsigned] [default 0]
```

cake will automatically assume this is a boolean and will transform the form field for it into a checkbox.

Comment: hey mark do you mind to explain, or share with me, how you emulate as "ArrayDatasource". It sounds like a nice approach.

Comment: A link to it should be on [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) for mainly 2.x - as well as the [awesome list](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp) for 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

Right out of the MySql Docs, states the following: 
"as explained later in this section—we strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration values"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html