# CakePHP: Error trying to generate a schema

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to start using CakePHP schema: `app/Console/cake schema generate`

I get the following error:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

This is confusing because the site is running fine, so the DB credentials in Config/database.php are correct.

**Update:**
Because I'm using MAMP, I added the following to my Config/database.php in the $defualt array:

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Now I don't get the original error, but rather some new ones:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.3.0 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Cake Schema Shell
---------------------------------------------------------------
Generating Schema...
Notice Error: Schema generation error: invalid column type enum('normal','unlimited_time','admin','extra_time') for Attempt.type does not exist in DBO in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php, line 616]

Notice Error: Schema generation error: invalid column type enum('in_progress','complete','canceled') for Attempt.status does not exist in DBO in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php, line 616]

Notice Error: Schema generation error: invalid column type enum('MC','FI','CS','CQ','TF') for AttemptedQuestion.type does not exist in DBO in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php, line 616]

Notice Error: Schema generation error: invalid column type enum('1','2','3') for Category.category_order does not exist in DBO in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php, line 616]

Error: Table choices for model Choice was not found in datasource default.
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3217): Model->setSource('choices')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php(260): Model->getDataSource()
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Console/Command/SchemaShell.php(149): CakeSchema->read(Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(388): SchemaShell->generate()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(199): Shell->runCommand('generate', Array)
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(67): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/Console/cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#7 {main}
```

Looks like CakePHP is freaking out about the ENUM fields.

Comment: @AD7six please have a look at the update above.

Comment: Enum isn't a supported field type as it's mysql-specific.

Comment: So I'm S.O.L for any of the Console/cake programs?

Comment: Note that your new question is unrelated to the original problem. Not necessarily but since the schema shell is going to interrogate the schema, and find something that's not supported - _that_ shell is going to find problems. Problems with enums are not cli specific, you'll find other problems as you use your app. Generally speaking you can work around enum problems. e.g you can define the schema in your model and say it's a char field instead.

Answer (score 2):

As described pretty definitively here...

[Cakephp + enum support : unable to save or select enum 0 and 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659838/cakephp-enum-support-unable-to-save-or-select-enum-0-and-1)

...CakePHP does not like ENUM fields. It looks like the Console tools related to the schema are going to work with them there.

Comment: "none" =)? Why would the schema of one model affect for example - the bake script (unless it loads that model _and_ requests the schema), or the test suite, or etc.

Comment: Revised it to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, I know. But I just fixed this issue yesterday while working in a really old project of mine.

If you still need this kind of solution, I posted on this git public repository.

https://github.com/matheuscmpm/cakephp-schema-enum

You basicly need to alter the Datasource/Database/Mysql.php file to insert the ENUM as an accepted type and them alter the Model/CakeSchema.php to handle them.

If you don't want to alter your cakephp 2.x files, you can copy them to your project app folder, just like I did. In this README.md file, you can see what exactly I changed in this both files, you can replicate the same solution to handle SET type fields as well.

I just did that to work with MySQL, so with you need to another database, you will also need to change a couple things in others datasource/database files.

Cheers.